# Simple "Variable" Bash File

Tags: bash, shell-script

I just want to make a bash file that takes a file name as a parameter. In that bash file, I want to take the name before the extension and have it as a "variable", to use in other places. For example, if I was to run `bash_script_name sample.asm`, the bash script would run:

```
nasm -f elf sample.asm
ld -s -o sample sample.o io.o
```

So basically the form of `bash_script_name $().asm`

```
nasm -f elf $().asm
ld -s -o $() $().o io.o
```

... however I would do that in bash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first argument to the script will be in `$1`. You can use a [bash string replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to pull the extension; this removes everything from the last occurrence of `.` forward, and stores the result in `$filename`:

```
filename="${1%.*}"
```

Then you can use `$filename` in your script wherever you want:

```
nasm -f elf "$filename.asm"
ld -s -o "$filename" "$filename".o io.o
```

Answer (score 0):

[This particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403489/1408426) to a similar question on Stack Overflow seems to have been very well thought out.
It includes logic to deal with files with no dots in them ("somefile"), and files with multiple dots in them ("somefile.tar.gz").